# How to iterate through a List<Object> or get elements of the list?

Tags: android, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working in an Android project with Firebase, I want to get information about a bar, I think I'm getting data correctly but I have some nodes in database structure like "open hours" in that node there is info like open and closes hour, start and end time of happy hours. I'm retrieving that node in a `List<Object>` like this:

This is my `ValueEventListener`

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        long value = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        Log.d("Bar", "No. of children: " + value);

        for (DataSnapshot districtSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String district = districtSnapshot.getKey();

            for (DataSnapshot barSnapshot: dataSnapshot.child(district).getChildren()) {

                Bar bar = barSnapshot.getValue(Bar.class);
                String name = bar.getName();
                String address = bar.getAddress();
                List<String> photos = bar.getPhotos();
                List<Object> hours = bar.getHours();
                double latitude = bar.getLatitude();
                double longitude = bar.getLongitude();

                barsList.add(new Bar(name, address, latitude, longitude, photos));

                Log.d("Bar", "Lat: " + latitude);
                Log.d("Bar", "Long: " + longitude);
                Log.d("Bar", "Photos: " + photos.toString());
                Log.d("Bar", "Hours String: " + hours.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};

mPostReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In `Log.d("Bar", "Hours String: " + hours.toString());` I'm getting correct info in array, but I just don't know how to convert it to a way I can select for example **happyStart**:

> Hours String: [{happyStart=17, happyEnd=19, open=17, close=2},
>   {happyStart=17, happyEnd=18, open=16, close=2}]

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE, added Bar class:**

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Bar {
    private String address;
    private String name;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private List<Object> hours;
    private List<Object> beers;
    private List<String> photos;

    public Bar() { }

    public Bar(String name, String address, double latitude, double longitude, List<String> photos) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("name", name);
        result.put("address", address);
        result.put("photos", photos);
        result.put("hours", hours);
        result.put("longitude", longitude);
        result.put("latitude", latitude);
        result.put("beers", beers);

        return result;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public List<Object> getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public List<Object> getBeers() {
        return beers;
    }

    public List<String> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `Bar` class

Comment: `private List<Object> hours;`... Did you want to create an `Hour` class here?

Comment: I just posted my Bar class @Apoorv

Comment: By the way, `new Bar(name, address` etc. is pointless... You're already have a Bar object from `barSnapshot.getValue(Bar.class)`. You do not need to extract the fields to create a new object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
private List<Map<String, Integer>> hours;
```

Then, it would be

```
int happyStart = beer.getHours().get(0).get("happyStart");
```

`.get(0)` is added to get the first out of the list.

You can also try

```
for (Map<String, Integer> hours : beer.getHours()) {
    Log.d("happyStart", "" + hours.get("happyStart"));
}
```

---

Or, you need to continue mapping your Firebase structure into Java objects to have a `Hour` class.

Comment: Great, it works!, do you know how to go deeper in structure? I mean my "beers" field have a number (just like hours), and then there is "name, type and price" where price is another node containing data of price in happy hour and normal price for every bottle size (300ml, 500ml, etc)...

Comment: Anything you've mapped to an Object is really a TreeMap, but you are also able to define Your own Java classes much like you've done for Bar

Answer (score 0):

Create another class called `Hours`

```
public class Hours {
    private String happyStart;
    private String happyEnd;
    private String open;
    private String close;
}
```

Add all the getters and setters like the `Bar` class and then replace `private List<Object> hours;` with `private List<hours> hours;`.

Then you can retrieve whatever hours you like from the `List` object